# show images with grid view in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-web

I tried to use StaggeredGridView but it wont load anything on my page, not even just text. I haven't put images URLs yet cuz I want to test it out.

So far this is my code below:

```
 body: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: deviceSize.width,
              height: 650,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    'assets/Big Sur.jpg',
                    width: deviceSize.width,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        """\n\n\nA decentralized photography platform\nfor the devoted communities.""",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'PhoBlock',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 80,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: new Text('$index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
                return StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1);
              },
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            ),
```

This was from the body of the Scaffold widget. Please help me as I'm trying to figure out how to use this new StaggeredGridView widget...

Comment: use Column  and remove listview

Comment: you can also use Expanded and add gridview in child of expanded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Column` and `Expanded` to control size 
code snippet

```
Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          width: deviceSize.width,
          //height: 650,
          child: Stack(
           ...
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 50,
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              width: deviceSize.width,
              //height: 650,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                    width: deviceSize.width,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        """\n\n\nA decentralized photography platform\nfor the devoted communities.""",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 30,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'PhoBlock',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 80,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 50,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Text('$index'),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
                return StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1);
              },
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

working demo 2

[image]

full code 2

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
          return SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: constraints.copyWith(
                minHeight: constraints.maxHeight,
                maxHeight: double.infinity,
              ),
              child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
                Container(
                  width: deviceSize.width,
                  height: 450,
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.network(
                        'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
                        width: deviceSize.width,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      Stack(
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            """\n\n\nA decentralized photography platform\nfor the devoted communities.""",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 30,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'PhoBlock',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 80,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 500,
                  child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                    crossAxisCount: 4,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Text('$index'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) {
                      return StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 1);
                    },
                    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
          );
        }));
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks almost perfect! Is it possible to have the first column to be scrolled away too?

Comment: please see full code 2 and working demo 2. Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks.

Comment: I keep trying to have StaggeredGridView without the Expanded...it shows errors...do you think there's a way to show grids of images like that but able to scroll down along with the "header"? Like in Unsplash website you will see a big header image, and as i scroll down the header is scrolled away and proceed to view the images...dont get me wrong, your code works like charm! its just dont fit my own goal yet...